# Read primitive datatype values in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

**Note: Please do not downvote question as I tried searching but did not find anything. The question has already been marked duplicate.**

How to read primitive datatype values in Kotlin?

We can use Scanner object of java but I want to implement using readLine function of kotlin.

How do I scan numbers e.g num1 and num2 and perform some operation like sum ?

How do it convert following code to koltin without using scanner?

```
val sc = Scanner(System.in)
val num1 = sc.nextInt()
val num2 = sc.nextInt()
val sum = sum(num1, num2)
```

Comment: Take also a look at this, it has a lot of examples :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283393/reading-input-from-the-console-in-kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like:

```
fun main(vararg args: String) {
  val (a, b) = readLine()!!.split(' ')
  println(a.toInt() + b.toInt())
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of double exclamation marks in "readLine()!!"?

Comment: @AksharPatel It means that cannot content Null ;), see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342413/what-is-the-kotlin-double-bang, don't forget voting if you liked :)