# What's the difference between !! and ? in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. I want to know the difference between this two `!!` and `?` in below code.

Below, there are two snippets: the first uses `!!` for `mCurrentDataset` and another having `?` for same variable.

```
if(!mCurrentDataset!!.load(mDataSetString.get(mCurrentDataSelectionIndex), STORAGE_TYPE.STORAGE_APPRESOURCE))
{
    Log.d("MyActivity","Failed to load data.")
    return false
}
```

---

```
if(!mCurrentDataset?.load(mDataSetString.get(mCurrentDataSelectionIndex), STORAGE_TYPE.STORAGE_APPRESOURCE)!!)
{
    Log.d("MyActivity","Failed to load data.")
    return false
}
```

Comment: this document helps you lot https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Answer (score 168, accepted):

As it said in [Kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html), `!!` is an option for NPE-lovers :)

```
a!!.length
```

will return a non-null value of `a.length` or throw a **NullPointerException** if `a` is `null`:

```
val a: String? = null
print(a!!.length) // >>> NPE: trying to get length of null
```

---

```
a?.length
```

returns `a.length` if `a` is not `null`, and `null` otherwise:

```
val a: String? = null
print(a?.length) // >>> null is printed in the console
```

---

### **To sum up:**

```
+------------+--------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
| a: String? |           a.length |           a?.length |           a!!.length |
+------------+--------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
|      "cat" | Compile time error |                   3 |                    3 |
|       null | Compile time error |                null | NullPointerException |
+------------+--------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

*Might be useful: [What is a NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)*

Comment: if a?.length returns null, in that case also throws NPE. i am not getting that case.

Comment: I've edited my post trying to make it more clear for you. Feel free to ask more questions.

Answer (score 12):

**Safe Calls** operator

In Kotlin

```
var a = x?.length;
```

Equivalent code in Java

```
int a = valueOfInt();

int valueOfInt() {
    if (x != null) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Side chain rule**

```
bob?.department?.head?.name
```

it can be read as->

If `bob` is not null give me the `department` ,

if `department` is not null give me the `head`,

if `head` is not null give me the `name`.

If any of it is `null`, then it returns `null`

**? before Data type**

If ? used before data type like:

```
val b: String? = null
```

it means you can assign null value to it otherwise null value can't be assigned to it.

**The !! Operator**

For those who like to have **Null Pointer Exception (NPE)** in their program.

```
val l = b!!.length
```

this will return a non-null value of `b` if `b` is not null OR throw an NPE if `b` is null

Answer (score 11):

the precedence of operators `!`, `?.`, `!!` is `?.` > `!!` > `!`.

the `!!` operator will raising `KotlinNullPointerException` when operates on a `null` reference, for example:

```
null!!;// raise NullPointerException
```

the safe call `?.` operator will return `null` when operates on a `null` reference, for example:

```
(null as? String)?.length; // return null;
```

the `!!` operator in your second approach maybe raise `NullPointerException` if the left side is `null`, for example:

```
mCurrentDataset?.load(..)!!
    ^-------------^
           | 
when mCurrentDataset== null || load() == null a NullPointerException raised.
```

you can using the elvis operator  `?:` instead of the `!!` operator in your case, for example:

```
!(mCurrentDataset?.load(..)?:false)
```

Answer (score 10):

this is '!!' **double-bang operator** is always return not-null value and this is '?'  **safe call operator** returns value if value is not null, and null otherwise

This is unsafe nullable type (T?) conversion to a non-nullable type (T). It will throw NullPointerException if the value is null.

It is documented [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) along with Kotlin means of null-safety.

ref - [hotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342413/what-is-the-kotlin-double-bang)

Answer (score 10):

```
In Addition to what Alexander said and as shown in the docs too,
```

the `?.` safe call operator is very useful in chaining, something like this

```
student?.department?.hod?.name
```

if there is no student, returns null otherwise look for his department. If department doesn't exist returns null otherwise look for hod (head of department) and so on.

If any one of student, department or hod is null then the result will be null.

Answer (score 1):

SafeCall Operator(?):

```
var a: String = "abc"
a = null  //compile time error

val b: String? = null
val result = b?.length//returns null
```

Assertion Operator(!!):

```
 val b: String? = "dd" //any value or null 
 val l = b!!.length 
//this throws null pointer exception if b is null otherwise returns actual
```