# What is difference between !! and ? in kotlin's null safety?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I am a bit confused about the usage of `?` and `!!` in the following instance.

```
  lat = mLastLocation?.latitude.toString()
  longi = mLastLocation!!.longitude.toString()
```

Which null-safety operator should I be using?

Comment: You mean `mLastLocation?.latitude?.toString()`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No just `(mLastLocation )?` here why I use `?` or `!!`....

Comment: Surely this is explained by the documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Comment: They are different. The not-null assertion operator (`!!`) converts any value to a non-null type and throws an exception if the value is null. `?` is the "safe call" operator. So `b?.foo` returns `null` if `b` is null.

Comment: @lurker ohh got it! please elaborate as answer :)

Comment: It's all in the documentation that @PPartisan linked to.

Comment: @lurker ok thank you will do that!

Comment: @deHaar A platform type is denoted by a single `!` (could be nullable or non-null). The 'double bang' `!!` is something different: an *operator* to force a nullable type to a non-null version.

Comment: Duplicate [The difference between !! and ? in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44536114/the-difference-between-and-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR:

`?.` operator is safe. Use it when you are unsure about the chain nullability.

`!!.` operator is meant to be used **only** when you are sure that the previous chain operation result is not null. Otherwise, crash.

if `mLastLocation` is never null, feel safe about using `!!.` (And about rethinking a little bit your code), otherwise, use `?.`

## Introduction

You have hit one of the best (and most useful) points while coding in Kotlin.

> here which null safety operator I should use?

It depends on the behavior you want to achieve.
In Kotlin, you have to be **very** specific about what you want to do with null values, because the language is designed to be null-safe out of the box.
Of course, targeting the JVM brings *many* challenges to a programming language. The eventuality of having null values is one of these, and Kotlin, as we'll see, handles this in a really smart manner.

## Purpose

We could explain the full theory behind those two operators, but I believe an example is really all you need.
Suppose you have a class, called `Location`, which we will declare in a nullable variable.
In Kotlin, this is represented as `val location: Location?`
Let's also say `Location` class has a property called `lat`, which is a nullable String, and a `lon` non-nullable String.

```
data class User(val lat: String?, val lon: String)
```

## Operator `?.`

[Kotlin Safe Call Operator Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls)

This operator is the safe call operator.
If you use it in a call chain, it is checking that your code chain goes onto the next element just if the previous element is not null. Otherwise, null is retuned from the statement.

```
val location: Location? = getLocation()
println(location.lat)      // Compile-time error.
println(location?.lat)    // Works fine.
```

This happens because in the first case, the object before `?.` is nullable, thus the Kotlin Compiler infers that accessing a nullable property can lead to NPEs.

> `location` could be null or not-null.
> We just don't know what it will be, and the Kotlin environment strictly makes sure that you are handling the eventuality of that value being null, as the type of our references variable is defined as nullable.

However, a certain variable being null is something you developer may not know. Sometimes it is not even up to you to receive a null or non-null value.

In this case you can safely stick with `?`, knowing that this operator is your friend if you are unsure about whether what you're referencing will be null.

```
val location: Location = getSafeLocation()
val nullableLocation: Location? = getLocation()

// Fine, may print "null" or the value, if present. 
// println accepts nullable values
println(location.lar) 

// 100% sure it'll print the corrisponding String value
println(location.lon)

// May print "null", "null", or the lat String value.
// The first "null" is because the ? operator will check if
// nullableLocation is null. If it is, it stops the execution
// chain and returns null. Otherwise, it assumes nullableLocation is safe
// and goes on.
//
// The second "null" is because the value itself of lat
// is declared as String? and Kotlin knows it may be null.
// If println() did not accept null values, this call would fail,
// but instead it prints "null" in case lat is indeed null.
println(nullableLocation?.lat)

// Since lat was the last element of the chain, it is not
// delivered as the parameter type anymore, and thus if we
// want to read a property from it we have to ensure that it isn't null.
println(nullableLocation?.lat?.length)

// This, as you may guess, returns wither null in case nullableLocation is null,
// otherwise 100% sure it will print lon value, since it is not a String? but a String.
println(nullableLocation?.lon)
```

## Operator `!!.`

[Kotlin Double-Bang Operator Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator)

This is the dreaded double-bang operator.
Talking about syntax, it is very similar to `?.`, since it is used in the same place.

To describe it in a really simple way: if anything before the call is null, your code will crash. Instantly. Without warnings.
With `!!.` you're explicitly saying that

Kotlin has to ignore any type nullability marker and to perform the operation you intend, even though it enters in a kind of danger zone.
This is known as a force, because you're forcing the Kotlin environment to believe that the previous statement is not null.
This operator best use case is when porting another library to Kotlin, or while handling API RESTful responses, situations where null values may come in, but because of environment/platform reasons, you know that some value can not be null. This helps you bringing type safety in the Kotlin world in the first place, if used properly.

But for mainstream software, this feature is meant for a really specific and narrow usage: If you are 100% sure that the previous call is **not** null, go ahead.

```
val location: Location? = getLocation()
println(location!!.lon)
```

The previous code may crash if location is

## Which one to use

Both operators are type-transforming. They both turn nullable values into non-nullable ones. The way the do it is the changing factor.

As a general rule, if you're sure the value you are targeting is not null, use `!!.`, otherwise stick with `?.`

Answer (score 1):

if you define a variable as

```
var myFirstVar:String? = null
```

this means that "myFirstVar" can have a null value and when you use "myFirstVar" you should indicate whether or not it has a null value

```
myFirstVar!!.toString
```

in here you're saying that you're 100% that myFirstVar will not be null (maybe you've given it a value before calling it)

but if you use ?

```
myFirstVar?.toString
```

you're indicating that myFirstVar might have a null value, the ? will chick if myFirstVar is null or not, if it is then it will not convert it to string (the application will not crash) and if it wasn't then it will convert it to string, it is a safety check to reduce the null crashes.

Answer (score 1):

If a variable is declared as `null`able type, you have two options when using it.
Let's take this for example:

```
private var myButton: Button? = null
```

So you have two option for the `myButton`. You can evaluate it, or keep it as it is. But the program on the run doesn't know what you have done with the variable before. So, in order to be safe Kotlin language provides you with `?` and `!!` operators. One is for the safety of program, so it won't crash and cause a KNPE:

```
 myButton?.setOnClickListener{

}
```

If the button is null, the app won't crash. Now, if you are 100% sure that you have evaluated the Button with a value different from null, you can use `!!`:

```
myButton!!.setOnClickListener{

   }
```

In this case, if you run the program and the `myButton` is null, you will have a crash.

**Null Safety Myth**

However, this is not a null safety case (I guess). What people mean by null safety in Kotlin is exactly this:

```
private val myButton: Button = someButtonInitialization()
```

If you evaluate it to `null`, the compiler would yell at you because `Button` is a non `null`able type. Otherwise it would be `Button?`.

This is null safety IMO, and not `!!` or `?`.

Special case: You can have:

```
private lateinit var myButton: Button
```

If you never evaluate the `myButton` you will never have KNPE, but an `UninitializedPropertyException` which has nothing to do with Null threat or null safety.

Comment: these operators were designed to interact with existing Java classes. For example in Android are used extensively, since most of the APIs are written in Java.

Comment: didn't know that detail. I just recognized it as a feature. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's have an example

```
var a: String? = "Hello world!"

fun test1() {
    a?.trim()
}

fun test2() {
    a!!.trim()
}
```

The first decompiled function is:

```
public static final void test1() {
  String var10000 = a;
  if (var10000 != null) {
     String var0 = var10000;
     StringsKt.trim((CharSequence)var0).toString();
  }
}
```

The second decompiled function is:

```
public static final void test2() {
  String var10000 = a;
  if (var10000 == null) {
     Intrinsics.throwNpe();
  }
  String var0 = var10000;
  StringsKt.trim((CharSequence)var0).toString();
}
```

Where `Intrinsics.throwNpe();` is defined as:

```
public static void throwNpe() {
    throw sanitizeStackTrace(new KotlinNullPointerException());
}
```

So `a?.trim()` will do nothing if var `a` was null
So `a!!.trim()` will throw an exception if var `a` was null