# Enable/Disable buttons in fragment for Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to add a function to enable/disable some buttons in my fragment, however I am getting a compilation error

> "Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a
> nullable reciever"

I have tried a couple of different methods; from calling the button directly, to calling the activity where I would do the button work, but I get the same error:

```
private fun enableButtons(buttonState: Boolean) {
    (activity as MainActivity?).enableButtons(buttonState)
    //                         ^ error there
}
```

and

```
    var button = activity.findViewById(R.id.button0) as Button
    //                   ^ error here
    button.isEnabled = false
    button.isClickable = false
```

I'm pretty new to Kotlin and can't work out how can I access the buttons without passing in a view

Comment: Also, to answer your last question, in order to access the buttons without passing a view you may use viewBinding or dataBinding: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: you should simply make your statement nullable, you can't call enableButtons on a null object, so by adding ? after your closing bracket you are making sure enableButtons fun will not be called if the casting returns null.
(activity as MainActivity?)?.enableButtons(buttonState)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is kinda suggesting what you have to do:

> "Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable reciever"

Means that whatever variable you are using, might be null.
So if you tried running

```kotlin
(activity as MainActivity?).enableButtons(buttonState)
```

this might end up as:

```kotlin
null.enableButtons(buttonState)
```

which (you may already know) will cause a crash

All kotlin is asking for is an alternative (when the variable is in fact `null`) or a "promise" that the variable is not null (!!)

A simple fix would be just to use:

```
(activity as MainActivity?)!!.enableButtons(buttonState)
```

or just remove `?` after `MainActivity`

(more on `.?` and `!!` you can find here: [What's the difference between !! and ? in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44536114/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-kotlin))

Comment: Just noticed the second code bit, but I guess the solution is the same: var button = activity!!.findViewById(R.id.button0) as Button

Comment: But I would still recommend checking out viewBinding

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure if activity can be null you should use the following syntax:

```
(activity as MainActivity?)?.enableButtons(buttonState)
```

The others have suggested force unwrapping however that means if `activity` does end up being null your app **will** crash.

This goes for any optional value:

```
var button = activity?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button0)
```

now if you want to use that button again you can simply use the null safety syntax:

```
button?.setOnClickListener { 
    // do stuff           
}
```

For more information about null safety check this out:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#checking-for-null-in-conditions

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

Remove `?` in front of `MainActivity`

```
(activity as MainActivity).enableButtons(buttonState)
```

## Solution 2

Add `?` in front of `(activity as MainActivity?)`

```
(activity as MainActivity?)?.enableButtons(buttonState)
```

Note:    There are rare cases that MainActivity get's null. So, the best solution is above among is 1st one.