# Kotlin return null safe value from null-able value

Tags: kotlin

I have this function

```
fun <T> safe(t: T?): T {
    return Optional.ofNullable(t).orElseThrow { IllegalStateException("safe value should not be null") }
}
```

I use it to say I know that T is not null now so give me back the non null-able form of it.

So I use it like this, I declare

```
class SomeType(val someOtherType: SomeOtherType?)
```

But some `someOtherType` in another place is declared like so:

```
class SomeThirdType(val someOtherType: SomeOtherType)
```

So in `SomeType` I have this function:

```
class SomeType(val someOtherType: SomeOtherType?) {
  fun doSomeDamage(): SomeThirdType {
    //some work
    return SomeThirdType(safe(someOtherType))
  }
}
```

**I'm not happy with the `safe` function, is there a better way? I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Kotlin double-bang (!!) operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342413/what-is-the-kotlin-double-bang-operator)

Comment: Yes it does. But in my team we have a policy of not using !! is another way?

Comment: I think your `safe` is pretty equivalent to `!!` (except slower and producing slightly less useful exception message) and all reasons not to use it would apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin already gives you tools to work with nullable types. I would just use scope functions and/or elvis operator. In your specific case, elvis operator seems enough.

```
class SomeType(val someOtherType: SomeOtherType?) {
  fun doSomeDamage(): SomeThirdType {
    //some work
    return SomeThirdType(someOtherType ?: error("someOtherType should not be null"))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes that would work too but using safe function is neater and less noise in my view

Comment: “Kotlin already gives you tools”.  Indeed!  Nulls are a lot less scary in Kotlin, because you always know when they're possible, and the compiler won't let you do anything unsafe.  And the safe-call operator, the elvis operator, and a host of extension functions with nullable receivers make it much more pleasant to deal with nulls when they _can_ occur.  Don't be afraid of them!

Answer (score 0):

A "user" of the `SomeType` class would not expect a crash upon a simple `doSomeDamage()` function call. The `SomeType` is fully constructed and yet `doSomeDamage` will likely crash.
I personally prefer :

```kotlin
fun doSomeDamage(someOtherType: SomeOtherType): SomeThirdType // with no-arg constructor
```

or if `SomeOtherType` *really* does belong to `SomeType` (which I feel not):

```kotlin
fun doSomeDamage(): SomeThirdType? = someOtherType?.let{...}
```